# Microsoft Access Properties

Tags: ms-access

I am using Microsoft Access to build a database and I have created a form that uses radio buttons, combo boxes and text boxes. When the form loads, everything is set to default. I have three radio buttons and three corresponding combo boxes. I select a radio button which enables the combo box and I can select one of the choices listed. When I check a different radio button, how do I get the previous combo box selection to automatically clear/reset?

Answer (score 2):

In the event procedure where you enable/disable the combobox, you can set its `Value` property to its `DefaultValue` property.

e.g.

```
With Me.cbo1
    .Value = .DefaultValue
    .Enabled = False
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an option control group instead of seperate radio buttons, if you aren't.

```
Private Sub RadioButtonGroup_Change()  
dim dv1,dv2,dv3 as string  
dv1 = me.cbo1.defaultvalue  
dv2 = me.cbo2.defaultvalue  
dv3 = me.cbo3.defaultvalue  
If me.radiobuttongroup.optionvalue = 1 then  
with me.cbo2   
.value = .defaultvalue  
.enabled = false  
end with  
with me.cbo3   
.value = .defaultvalue  
.enabled = false  
end with  
Elseif me.radiobuttongroup.optionvalue = 2 then    
with me.cbo1  
.value = .defaultvalue  
.enabled = false  
end with  
with me.cbo3  
.value = .defaultvalue  
.enabled = false  
end with  
Else  
with me.cbo1  
.value = .defaultvalue  
.enabled = false  
end with  
with me.cbo2   
.value = .defaultvalue  
.enabled = false  
end with  
end if  
End Sub
```